# An determinant inequality of strictly diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Recently, I have seen a matrix inequality but don't know how to prove it. The inequality goes as follows.

Matrix A is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix.

[image of inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPsK3.png)

I encounter it in my numeric algebra textbook.
ISBN： 9787301211410  P134

Comment: https://planetmath.org/proofofdeterminantlowerboundofastrictdiagonallydominantmatrix

Comment: thanks! a great prove!

Comment: You are misusing the site. You already asked this question once, and your question was closed as off-topic. Then you posted the same question again.

Comment: Why I misusing the site?What should I do if I just want to get any prove to this inequality ?

Comment: I mean ,why my question was closed as off-topic? Really confused me as I am a beginner.

Comment: Thanks!Now I konw the difference between mathoverflow and mathmatita exchange !